# c# pasar datos de una clase a otra

Tags: c#, unity3d

Buenas! Tenia hecho un ejercicio donde creaba un button por cada fichero que leia en un xml.En el codigo que dejo abajo en la 4 linea paso los datos de juego al init de otra clase,y luego en la otra clase ya voy haciendo lo que quiera con esos datos.
Me preguntaba como podia hacer algo lo mas parecido pero con este codigo.

Codigo para crear botones y luego llamo al Init para pasar los datos

```
Código:
foreach (var juego in data.Juegos) {
            AppButton button = Instantiate(buttonPrefab);
            button.transform.SetParent(layout);
            button.Init(juego);
        }
```

codigo del init que esta en otra clase

```
Código:
public void Init(Juego game) {
        this.game = game;

        LoadTexture();
    }
```

y ahora con este codigo como podria hacer algo similar a lo de arriba? Quiero pasar los datos de data y imagenes al init que esta en otra clase.

```
Código:
if (Directory.Exists(rutasapp))
        {
            foreach (string dataApp in Directory.GetDirectories(rutasapp))
            {
                GameObject button = Instantiate(buttonPrefab) as GameObject;
                button.transform.SetParent(layout);
                button.name = "Button" + layout.childCount;


                foreach (string data in Directory.GetFiles(@dataApp).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".exe") || s.EndsWith(".lnk")))
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(@data) == ".exe")
                    {
                        button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => Process.Start(data));
                    }
                }




                foreach (string imagenes in Directory.GetFiles(@dataApp).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".png") || s.EndsWith(".jpg")))
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(@imagenes) == ".png")
                    {
                        string imgPath = imagenes;

                    }
                }
            }
```

el init de la otra clase es igual al de arriba,que tengo que modificar aqui?

```
Código:
public void Init(Juego game) {
        this.game = game;
        LoadTexture();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Existen muchas maneras de hacer lo que pide, le dejare algunas, no nesecesariamente una es mejor que la otra, dependera de muchos factores, ademas de sus conocimientos, en cuanto a como usarlar y cuando usarlas.

---

## **tl;dr**

- tener una variable del tipo de la clase que recive los datos, dentro de la clase desde la que se quiere enviar los datos. asignamos la referencia y llamamos al metodo pasandole los parametros. Para asignar la referencia puede usar:

  - basado en Tag: `su_variable = GameObject.FindWithTag("nombre_tag_gameobject").GetComponent<LaClaseQueReciveLosDatos>();`
  - basado en pasar el GameObject desde el editor y usando `su_variable = ob.GetComponent<LaClaseQueReciveLosDatos>();`
- usando delegates;
- empleando UnityEvents

---

**1º** basanda en tag;

mirar por internet si no sabe como crear y usar `tag` en unity y aplicarlo a los objetos, **creo que la respuesta va ha ser un poco larga**, asi que si, tengo espacio le dejo unas capturas, de como se hace.

Una vez que tenga el `tag` puesto en el `GameObject`.

Modificamos el codigo;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

//cambiar nombre por el nombre de la clase suya que tiene los datos (el script)
class LaClaseQueTieneLosDatos: MonoBehaviour{ 
//..

    //cambiar nombre por el nombre de la clase suya que va a recivir los datos (el script)    
    private LaClaseQueReciveLosDatos receptora = null; 
    private List<string> data = new List<string>();
    private List<string> imagenes = new List<string>();

    void Awake(){
        receptora = GameObject.FindWithTag("nombre_tag_gameobject").GetComponent<LaClaseQueReciveLosDatos>();
    }
//..

            foreach (string dataApp in Directory.GetDirectories(rutasapp))
            {
                GameObject button = Instantiate(buttonPrefab) as GameObject;
                button.transform.SetParent(layout);
                button.name = "Button" + layout.childCount;


                foreach (string data in Directory.GetFiles(@dataApp).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".exe") || s.EndsWith(".lnk")))
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(@data) == ".exe")
                    {
                        button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => Process.Start(data));

                     -->   this.data.Add(data); //añades en cada iterecion el string data
                    }
                }




                foreach (string imagenes in Directory.GetFiles(@dataApp).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".png") || s.EndsWith(".jpg")))
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(@imagenes) == ".png")
                    {
                        string imgPath = imagenes;

                       --> this.imagenes.Add(imagenes); //añades en cada iterecion el string imagenes
                    }
                }
            }

 //..
//Ahora la historia de pendera de si tienes acceso en esta clase a una instancia de Juego o similar "si se puede crear una ect"
//despues seguiremos aqui

}
```

si tienes acceso a `Juego` de alguna manera:

puede añadir algo asi en la clase que va a recivir los datos

**LaClaseQueReciveLosDatos.cs**

```
//..
private List<string> data = null
private List<string> imagenes = null

public void Init(Juego game, List<string> data, List<string> imagenes) {

    this.game = game;
    this.data = data;
    this.imagenes = imagenes;

    LoadTexture();
}
//..
```

si NO tienes acceso a Juego de alguna manera:

añadir algo asi en la clase que va a recivir los datos

**LaClaseQueReciveLosDatos.cs**

```
//..
private List<string> data = null
private List<string> imagenes = null

public void Init(Juego game) {

    this.game = game;

    LoadTexture();
}
public void SetData(List<string> data) {

    this.data = data;
}
public void SetImagenes(List<string> imagenes) {

    this.data = data;
}

//..
```

SI puede usar propiedades en lugar del usar el seter asi, pero recuerda que en unity no puede crear propiedades con valores por defecto si usar la reflexion "hasta donde yo se" pues usa c# 4 y esto creo que es permitido solo desde c# 6.

Ahora volviendo donde lo dejamos.

si elegimos la primera opcion usamos esto;

```
//..
receptora.Init(instacia_game, data, imagenes);
//..
```

si elegimos la segunda opcion usamos esto;

```
//..
receptora.SetData(data);
receptora.SetImagenes(imagenes);
//..
```

si usa esta ultima opcion tiene que asegurarse que la instancia de LaClaseQueReciveLosDatos (osea el objeto si esta dentro el script) ya esta instanciada "que ya la creo" (**SI TIENE COMPORTAMIENTOS** extraños puede ser cosa del `Script execution order` pero no soy adivino, solo se lo comento para que pueda mirar por internet en que consite y como usarlo.

---

**2º** forma, sin usar los `tag`, solo se cambia lo siguiente, el resto es igual.

```
//cambiar nombre por el nombre de la clase suya que tiene los datos
class LaClaseQueTieneLosDatos: MonoBehaviour{ 
//..
    public GameObject ob = null;
    //cambiar nombre por el nombre de la clase suya que va a recivir los datos
    private LaClaseQueReciveLosDatos receptora = null; 
    private List<string> data = new List<string>();
    private List<string> imagenes = new List<string>();

    void Awake(){
        receptora = ob.GetComponent<LaClaseQueReciveLosDatos>();
    }
//..
```

Ahora desde el editor **arrastramos el objeto**, que tiene el script que 
**recive los datos**, **dentro** del campo del script con el nombre ob, que esta en el objeto que **tiene los datos**.

---

**3º** Ahora otra forma usando delegates.

**LaClaseQueTieneLosDatos.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

class LaClaseQueTieneLosDatos: MonoBehaviour{

    public int dato;

    public delegate void SeActualiza();
    public static event SeActualiza OnSeActualiza;

    void Start(){
        ActualizarDato(15);
    }

    void ActualizarDato(int dato){
        this.dato += dato;

        if(OnSeActualiza != null){
            OnSeActualiza();
        }
    }
}

LaClaseQueReciveLosDatos.cs

using UnityEngine;

class LaClaseQueReciveLosDatos: MonoBehaviour{
    void OnEnable(){
        //Subscribe to HealthUpdate event
        LaClaseQueTieneLosDatos.OnSeActualiza += HandleSiSeActualiza;
    }

    void HandleSiSeActualiza (){
        Debug.Log ("SeActualiza");
    }
}
```

https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events

*si esta manera se adapta a lo que quiere solo tiene que ajustarla*

---

**4º** forma es haciendo uso de UnityEvents.

Pienso que es mejor que mire lo siguientes link:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityEvents.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mcRJAesscg
- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent_1.html

dos son de la documentacion de Unity y otro es un video, todos estan en ingles, pero puede mirarlos y si tiene alguna duda puede mirar por internet o publicar una pregunta en especifico, sobre la parte en la cual tiene dudas
pues creo que explicarlo en texto ahora mismo, se hace un poco confuso de entender si no se cuenta con alguna base, y usar imagenes como apoyo se haria mucho mas larga.